# Como disponibilizar um arquivo de vídeo para visualização no browser como o PDF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Como disponibilizar um arquivo para download e para visualização em browser?
Como exemplo, arquivos do tipo **pdf** e **mp4**.

Quando desejo disponibilizar para download o arquivo eu simplesmente uso a seguinte rotina:

```cs
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/Biblioteca/") + fileName;
    return File(path, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

Ao tentar disponibilizar para ser visualizado no browser eu tentei o seguinte:

```cs
public ActionResult OpenFile(string fileName)
{
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/Biblioteca/") + fileName;
    return File(path, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path));
}
```

A diferença é que não informei a propriedade referênte ao nome do arquivo para download.

Em meu computador (modo ***debug***) o vídeo e o PDF são demostrados no browser como esperado.

[image: Vídeo no browser]

Mas ao tentar disponibilizar no servidor, ambos não são abertos e dessa forma é feito download do arquivo.

Primeiramente eu estava tentando abrir o arquivo diretamente, sem passar um controller e uma action, então hora dava certo, hora não, pois dava erro de arquivo não encontrado. Provavelmente devido ao tamanho do nome.

Para que fosse possível eu precisei registrar o ***mime*** no IIS do servidor (**video/mp4**).

Mas como disse, diretamente costuma dar erro e por questão de boas práticas, desejo não acessar o arquivo diretamente.

Então, **como disponibilizar os arquivos para visualização no browser, quando possível?**

Answer (score 1):

Você não deve servir o vídeo como um arquivo, e sim como um *Stream*.

Para isso, implemente uma classe que prepare o *Stream* do vídeo para você:

```
public class VideoStream
{
   private readonly string _arquivo;

   public VideoStream(string arquivo)
   {
      _filename = @"C:\Seu\Diretorio\De\Video\" + arquivo;
   }

   public async void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content = null, TransportContext context = null)
   {
      try
      {
          var buffer = new byte[65536];

          using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
          {
              var length = (int)video.Length;
              var bytesRead = 1;

              while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
              {
                  bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                  await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                  length -= bytesRead;
              }
          }
      }
      catch (HttpException ex)
      {
         return;
      }
      finally
      {
         outputStream.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

Aqui podemos ter duas soluções: uma para MVC, outra para Web API.

### Web API

```
public class VideosController : ApiController
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(string videoNome)
   {
      var video = new VideoStream(videoNome + ".mp4");

      var response = Request.CreateResponse();
      response.Content = new PushStreamContent(video.WriteToStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"));

      return response;
   }
}
```

### MVC

Implemente antes um `VideoResult`:

```
public class VideoResult : ActionResult 
{ 
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
    { 
        var queryString = context.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        var videoStream = new VideoStream(queryString["videoNome"]);
        // Header
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + queryString["videoNome"] + ".mp4"); 
        videoStream.WriteToStream(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
    } 
}
```

E a *Action*:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string videoNome)
    { 
        return new VideoResult(); 
    }
```